# How to use the UseState hook as the name of a property in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects

In my project, i want to make an axios post request.

I want that if the **useState** hook is set to **true**, the name of the property is **different**, than if it is set to **false**.

For example:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(); //like useEmail

const object ={
property1 like name: someProperty,                      //like name value
property2 like email/phonenumber: someOtherproperty    //like email/phonenumber value
}

setState(true)// object property2 = email
setState(false)//object property2 = number
```

Is it possible?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false);

const object = {
  [state ? 'email' : 'name']: 'something'
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `const obj = { [state ? 'email' : 'name']: 'something' }`

Comment: Makes more sense now, I couldn't decipher the question

Comment: Thanks, i didnt knew you coud do if else in [] in a object.